# Why does Perl allow pass arguments by reference?

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference

I'm wondering why Perl has ability to pass argument by reference to function?
I know that neither Python, nor Ruby doesn't have such feature.

Comment: Do you mean implicit or explicit passing of reference? Perhaps provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: Why would you want to omit the ability to pass arguments by reference?

Comment: It seems like `@_` containing aliases was an accidental feature that people came to depend on as far back as the Perl 3 days—or maybe that was with `for`. Searches of the p5p archive and git repo have come up empty, but @tchrist or @merlyn will know the answer.

Comment: @TLP, I mean prepending variable by backslash ``\``.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman, I think it's quite erroneous approach to programming — it's more difficult to read code which can rebind external to function variable names inside function call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's useful to distinguish one thing from another.

(1) Passing arguments to a subroutine *by reference*. This is useful in Perl because the language passes all arguments to a subroutine as an *undifferentiated list of values*. Without the ability to passed data structures by reference, the designer of a function taking two lists, for example, would not be able to keep the lists separate. In addition, if the data structures are large, passing them by reference can provide a performance gain.

```
process_two_lists( @x,  @y); # Can't distinguish the lists.
process_two_lists(\@x, \@y); # Can.
```

Because Python and Ruby are designed differently, they don't require this distinction in how arguments are passed. A similar method in Python or Ruby would receive two distinct arguments (two objects representing lists `x` and `y`).

(2) Perl's behavior whereby `@_` serves as an *alias* to the passed arguments, allowing the subroutine to modify data as perceived by the caller.

```
sub add_ten_to_me {
    $_[0] += 10;
}

my $x = 1;
add_ten_to_me($x);
say $x;            # 11  Amazing!
```

Python and Ruby can do this type of thing as well; however, there are some qualifications. Python distinguishes between *mutable* and *immutable* objects. If you pass something mutable to a Python method (a list, for example), the method is able to modify the data structure. So a Python version of `process_two_lists` would be able to modify both `x` and `y`. However, a function receiving immutable objects (an integer, for example) would not. Thus, a direct Python analog of `add_ten_to_me` would not work. [I believe that similar points could be made about Ruby, but I'm less familiar with the details at this point.]

Comment: I think #2 is what people usually call "pass-by-reference". #1 is called passing a reference

Answer (score 6):

Passing arguments by reference can give significant performance improvements.

Answer (score 4):

Perl gives you the choice. I think it's part of that TIMTOWTDI idea. It's a flexible method, so you can do what you need. If you access the argument as `$_[0]` then it's the same object. If you shift it or copy it to a lexical, it's by value.

So think of it this way. Most code is by value, but by reference is there when you need it.